# How to define a random infinite point cloud and find Delaunay triangles at any coord?

Tags: point-cloud

For a map generator with islands I'm looking for an algorithm that for a given random seed defines am infinite point cloud of 2D points that looks decently random and covers all of infinity (a simple grid is out because it would look horribly boring) and a function F(x, y) that returns the Delaunay triangle(s) containing the coordinates (x, y).

Or something that returns all points of the cloud in a given radius.

Comment: The output of an algorithm does not contain an infinite amount of information. If you just want to scatter points about a large square, you can just let the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of each point be random numbers uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$ and independent of each other, and let these points be chosen independently of each other. I think there exists on-the-shelf software for Delaunay triangulations.

Comment: You are talking about generating the points randomly. That certainly works for a finite square. But I need an INFINITE square. Which also means an infinite number of points. The point cloud has to remain abstract and at any one time I only need information on it for a small region.